# Provider Hosted Apps Launch Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a provider hosted app (a normal asp.net web forms application) deployed on a typical web server IIS 7.5.

While launching the app from SharePoint Site in Office 365 Multi Tenant, it's throwing the below issue on App launch.

On capturing details using Fiddler, found the following when the app is launched

SPAppToken=&SPSiteUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fspdev%2Famsdev%2Famitamsdev&SPSiteTitle=amitamsdev&SPSiteLogoUrl=%2Fsites%2Fspdev%2FSiteAssets%2Flogo.gif&SPSiteLanguage=en-US&SPSiteCulture=en-US&SPRedirectMessage=EndpointAuthorityMatches&SPCorrelationId=31477a9c-2902-204a-8393-67eced1a10b8&SPErrorCorrelationId=31477a9c-2902-204a-8393-67eced1a10b8&
**SPErrorInfo=The+requested+operation+requires+an+HTTPS+%28SSL%29+channel.++Ensure+that+the+target+endpoint+address+supports+SSL+and+try+again.++Target+endpoint+address**

The SPErrorInfo Part is interesting. I am unable to confirm whether we really need the remote site to be configured for https?

Additional Information - Identity Provider is ACS and it is a low trust app.

Can someone suggest?

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi

Answer (score 1):

In a production environment, you should always be using HTTPS. If you don't, you're exposing yourself (and your organization) to many risks.

If this is your development environment and you are confident this isn't an issue, you may want to look at the accepted answer to [this question on the MSDN forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/487112d7-5085-4316-bd6e-c81ad165cc21/error-following-site-across-farm-using-shared-user-profile-service-application), which mentions the same error message. Their solution to bypass the HTTPS checking:

```
$c = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$c.AllowMetadataOverHttp = $true
$c.AllowOAuthOverHttp=$true
$c.Update()
```

Comment: Unsure if this fits in for my scenario where I have an O365 Multi-Tenant and a classic web server. The details mentioned above seemed to be for configuring trust between two SharePoint Farms and using http for the same. I am trying to validate around the above for O365.

Comment: Considering I am talking about O365, I am still not clear whether it's supported. In any case, the above command is for an On-Premise environment and there is no equivalent Get-SPO* command. BTW an MSDN reference that does say Https is needed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179932(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When packaging the SharePoint App from Visual Studio, you must ensure that the URL you use is using HTTPS:

[image: Visual Studio Package SharePoint App Dialog]

In IIS, add an HTTPS binding to the site to achieve this. You would have to reupload the App to SharePoint after packaging it with the new HTTPS URL.

More information [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2015/07/errors-in-sharepoint-apps-add-ins.html).